# Composing Music for Dholak Instrument in Jfugue

Tags: java, jfugue

I compose music in java with JFUGUE. Jfugue contains some Indian instruments like Sitar and Shanai etc., but I need to compose for Dholak or Tabla (percussion instruments), which are not enlisted in the list of 127 instruments in Jfugue. Is there any way or method to add or replace my needed instrument in Jfugue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFugue uses the same instruments that are defined by the MIDI standard. You may be able to find a Dholak or Tabla instrument as a SoundFont, which you can load into Java if you are using the Gervill synthesizer (or versions of Java that include the Gervill implementation, which are JDK 7 and later).

See also: [Can we create our own composition using Soundfont and JFugue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161634/can-we-create-our-own-composition-using-soundfont-and-jfugue)